# \clist_item and \pgfmathsetmacro causing an error

Tags: expl3, xparse, pgfmath

My main aim was to be able to use more than 9 arguments when defining a new command. Therefore i am using the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{mmmm}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ma}{\clist_item:nn{#2}{3}}
\ma
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\test{1,2,3}{4,5,6}{7,8,9}{10,11,12}

\end{document}
```

This code works. But when i do the following,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{mmmm}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ma}{\clist_item:nn{#2}{3}}
\ma
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\mb}{6}
\test{1,2,3}{4,5,\mb}{7,8,9}{10,11,12}

\end{document}
```

, then i get an error.

(! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `6' or` 6@' (in '6').
See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.)

Can someone help me please?

If there is something else, better than \clist_item to use, then i am curious to know about it.

---

EDIT 1:
First of all, thanks a lot. Both solutions work. I am still not sure which solution is to prefer and why. But, my question as i posted it, is answered.
But, i am facing another error again.
I am trying to do something like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{mmmm}{
\exp_args:Nne\expandafter\pgfmathsetmacro\csname\clist_item:nn{#1}{1}x\endcsname{
\clist_item:nn{#2}{1}%Here some calculation is done, e. g.: cos(\clist_item:nn{#3}{2})*(\clist_item:nn{#4}{3}) (Therefore, i am using pgfmathsetmacro)
}
\csname\clist_item:nn{#1}{1}x\endcsname
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\test{pa}{1,2,3}{4,5,6}{7,8,9}

\end{document}
```

I want to use this code for defining points, which i then use for drawing with tikz.
I want to use the argument pa (meaning point a) of the 1st comma separated list to give the pgfmath macro the name \pax (meaning point a x coordinate).
Here is an example of what i am trying to do of an old (working) code using \newcommand:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\newcommand{\testb}[4]{
\expandafter\pgfmathsetmacro\csname#1x\endcsname{
#2
}
\expandafter\pgfmathsetmacro\csname#1y\endcsname{
#3
}
\expandafter\pgfmathsetmacro\csname#1z\endcsname{
#4
}
\coordinate (#1) at (\csname#1x\endcsname,\csname#1y\endcsname,\csname#1z\endcsname);
\node at (#1) {\(#1\)};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\linewidth}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\testb{pa}{1}{1}{0}
\draw[tdplot_main_coords] (0,0,0) -- (pa);
\draw[tdplot_main_coords] (0,0,0) -- ++(\pax,0,0) -- ++(0,\pay,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

What is the correct way to use \clist_item: for giving a pgfmath macro a name?

Comment: don't edit to ask new questions after answer have been posted, ask a new question. But you don't say what you want `\exp_args:Nne\expandafter\pgfmathsetmacro\csname` to do but it is weird and applies `e` expansion to `\csname`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You do not need pgf at all here, but perhaps you need it in your real document. You just need to expand `clist_item:n` before passing the argument to pgf.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{mmmm}{
\exp_args:Nne\pgfmathsetmacro{\ma}{\clist_item:nn{#2}{3}}
\ma
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\mb}{6}
\test{1,2,3}{4,5,\mb}{7,8,9}{10,11,12}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have accept your answer as the solution. Thank you. I have edited my original question and added another question. Can this be done, too, somehow?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what would be the reason for `\pgfmathsetmacro`.

Anyway, in order for this to work you have to further expand the result.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfmath}
%\usepackage{xparse} % no longer necessary

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{mmmm}
 {
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ma}{\use:e{\clist_item:nn{#2}{3}}}
  \ma
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\mb}{6}
\test{1,2,3}{4,5,\mb}{7,8,9}{10,11,12}
\test{1,2,3}{4,5,6}{7,8,9}{10,11,12}

\end{document}
```

Comment: so slow:-).....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But without `\exp_args:...`

Answer (score 1):

Using my new package,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pythonimmediate}


\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
from pythonimmediate import newcommand, get_arg_str, print_TeX
@newcommand
def test():
  arg1 = get_arg_str()
  arg2 = get_arg_str()
  arg3 = get_arg_str()
  arg4 = get_arg_str()
  print_TeX(r"\pgfmathsetmacro{\ma}{" + str(arg2.split(',')[2]) + "}")
\end{pycode}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\mb}{6}
\test{1,2,3}{4,5,\mb}{7,8,9}{10,11,12}

\ma


\end{document}
```

For debugging, you can add something like the following to the source code

```
print()
print()
print()
print(r"we're going to execute the following: ======== \pgfmathsetmacro{\ma}{" + str(arg2.split(',')[2]) + "}")
print()
print()
print()
```

which prints out

```
we're going to execute the following: ======== \pgfmathsetmacro{\ma}{\mb }
```

hopefully should be self-explanatory.